# Understanding Map get method

Tags: java, dictionary

Reading the JavaDocs for `Map#get(Object key)` I didn't quite understand what actually the methods returned. [The quote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29)

> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or `null` if
>   this map contains no mapping for the key.

What do they mean *returns the value*? May it be a new object created as a copy of the mapped object? I worte the following simple program:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Map<Integer, MyClass> m = new HashMap<>();
    m.put(1, new MyClass());
    MyClass mc = m.get(1);
    mc.i = 15;
    System.out.println(m.get(1).i); //prints 15
}

private static class MyClass{
    public int i = 10;
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/upO6v4)

Is it reliable that by changing the state of an object returned by `get(Object key)` I change the actual mapped object or it's an implementation specific and an arbitrary implementaion of `Map` should not hold it?

Comment: `Is it reliable that by changing the state of an object returned by get(Object key) I change the actual mapped object` - yes, because otherwise `Map` had to enforce to hold objects providing a copy constructor.

Comment: What does your demo program do that you don't expect? What did you think it would print instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, yes.

The map keeps references to the objects added to it. Therefor, when you call get, you get the reference to the original object and any change made is for good.

The docs state [1]: 
*Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is a key in the map. A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a map to contain itself as a key. While it is permissible for a map to contain itself as a value, extreme caution is advised: the equals and hashCode methods are no longer well defined on such a map.*

Therefor, even they note that you can change the mapped object, but certain things should be kept in mind if used as a key when changing fields that affect the equals return value.

[1] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Answer (score 1):

What Map does is it associates keys with the object references, so whenever you retrieve an object using get method, you actually retrieve the reference of the object. So whenever you perform any manipulation using this reference then you manipulate the actual object.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is potentially some confusion here in the use of an overloaded term like "value". This is not "value" as in "pass-by-value", but rather in the sense of the first sentence of [Map's Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

> [A Map is] An object that maps keys to values

The value is just the instance stored for a given key.

So the following should be true:

```
K key = getTheKey();
V value = getTheValue();

Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(key, value);
assert value == map.get(key);  // The call to get returns the same instance that you put into the map.
```

No copying of the instance can be done when you call `get` - in the general case, it is unknown how to create a copy of an object.